# Need to optimise select query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, indexing, query-optimization

I have a query that does a select with joins from multiple tables that contains in total about 90 million rows. I only need data from the last 30 days. The problem is that when I run the select query the sql server throws a timeout while the query is running and new records are not created during this time frame. This query takes about 5 seconds to complete.

I would like to optimise this query so that it wont go through the entire tables looking at the datetime and would only search from the latest entries.

Right now it seems that I would need to index datetime column. Please advise if I need to create indexes or if there is another way to optimise this query.

```
SELECT [table1].Column1 AS InvoiceNo,
       'ND' AS VATRegistrationNumber,
       'ND' AS RegistrationNumber,
       Column2 AS Country,
       [table2].Column3 + ' ' + [table2].Column4 AS Name,
       CAST([table1].Column5 AS date) AS InvoiceDate,
       'SF' AS InvoiceType,
       '' AS SpecialTaxation,
       '' AS VATPointDate,
       ROUND([table1Line].Column6, 2) AS TaxableValue,
       CASE
            WHEN [table1Line].Column7 = 9 THEN 'PVM2'
            WHEN [table1Line].Column7 = 21 THEN 'PVM1'
            WHEN [table1Line].Column7 = 0 THEN 'PVM14'
       END AS TaxCode,
       CAST([table1Line].Column7 AS int) AS TaxPercentage,
       table1Line.Column8 - ROUND([table1Line].Column6, 2) AS Amount,
       '' AS VATPointDate2,
       [table1].Column1 AS InvoiceNo,
       '' AS ReferenceNo,
       '' AS ReferenceDate,
       [table1].CustomerPersonID AS CustomerID
FROM [table1]
     INNER JOIN [table2] ON [table1].CustomerPersonID = [table2].ID
     INNER JOIN [table3] ON [table2].Column9 = [table3].ID
     INNER JOIN [table1Line] ON [table1].ID = [table1Line].table1ID
     INNER JOIN [table4] ON table1Line.TaxID = Tax.ID
     INNER JOIN [table5] ON [table1].CompanyID = Company.ID
     INNER JOIN table6 ON [table1].SalesChannelID = table6.ID
WHERE Column5 LIKE '%date%'
  AND table6.id = 5
   OR table6.id = 2
  AND Column5 LIKE '%date%'
ORDER BY Column5 DESC;
```

Comment: You say you need data of last 30 dates, but I don't see any such criteria in your `where`. On the other hand, I see some very spooky `like '%date%'` stuff. Can you elaborate on how the date selection is being done?

Comment: `Column5 LIKE '%date%'` isn't SARGable, meaning that a full scan of the table (which ever table it's from, you don't qualify it) would need to be completed; this won't be performant. You also, oddly, check `Column5 LIKE '%date%'` *twice*; it is both your first and last clause in your `WHERE`. Also, it generally advised to use parentheses (`()`) when using `OR` in a `WHERE`; many people get the priorities wrong, and so putting them in removes that ambiguity.

Comment: *"Right now it seems that I would need to index datetime column"* Which columns is your `datetime` column? Your `WHERE` appears to reference a `varchar` column (`Column5`) and an `int` column (`table6.id`), and i don't see any obvious candidates in your `ON` clauses that would be a `datetime` either. Indexing your `datetime` column, which ever column it is, doesn't seem like it'll help in any way to the performance of the above query.

Comment: What we really need here, initially, is your query plan. Can you [Paste the Plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/)?

Comment: I tried using %2022-05% within the script but I suspect it does the search through the entire table.

Comment: @Larnu. Yes I will do that, just need to find a timeframe when there are less purchases made. I will post that as soon as I get it :)

Comment: Dates aren't strings, @SimasKasparaitis , don't treat them like one. If you want a date range, *use* a date range: `WHERE SomeDate >= {Some Date} AND SomeDate < {Another Date}`

Comment: @larnu Ok. I will try doing the search using >= operator and If no improvement I will post the execution plan.

Comment: _The problem is that when I run the select query the sql server throws a timeout while the query is running..._ No, it doesn't. SQL Server queries can run for days and weeks, left unchecked. Whatever environment you executed this code from threw a client-side timeout waiting for a response.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning You say that the problem may be that the table is locked from new entries while  SELECT is running and thats why our software that is connected to this database is giving timeout error?

Comment: For this question to be answerable, we need to see relevant table and index definitions, and please share the query plan using the above link. Otherwise we cannot answer this properly. It would also help if you could tell us how the different filters and joins limit the result: do any of them reduce the number of rows from the big table drastically?

Comment: Just so you understand, `WHERE Column5 LIKE '%date%'` can't be optimized by any index. It's probably the slowest WHERE clause one can write.

Comment: @O.Jones now I am using where Column5 >='2022-05-01'. Query takes about two seconds when I am running it for the first time. Looks promising.

Comment: Although where condition has improved execution time  but still timeout is received. I will post the execution plan on the following days.

Comment: https://www.transfernow.net/dl/20220610SW3DKCqf

Comment: Any suggestions how to improve this query?

Comment: There is a clustered key lookup that costs 67 percent everything else costs no more than 17 percent. Even this key lookup has high percentage this still wont explain why the server has timeouts.

Comment: I would suggest using the ACTUAL query, not trying to "mask" table names (table1-6), nor columns (column1, 5, 7, whatever).  You are not posting actual data, but making things read poorly for sample does not work well here.  Ex: Your "Table4" is that really TAX table per JOIN.  Similarly Table5 is Company?  Why not just include actual table names.  Also, as others noted, please confirm is the date COLUMN5 actually a date/datetime field?  Indexes can be optimized to help.  please EDIT your existing post and put the ACTUAL query you need assistance, not a masked version.

Answer (score 0):

First things first, each database runs a little differently because the optimizer has been running and figuring out how the unique circumstances can be improved and continuously tries to make common things run better.

There's also versioning differences that also play a part is the performance of the server.

Besides that stuff, Here's a few things to do to optimize this query.
When working with Joins, Your Joined table comes first then compare against the already specified table.

For example t2 checks against t1:

```
select t1.name, t2.car
from customers as t1
left join purchases as t2
on t2.customerid = t1.customerid
```

The next thing I see is the Like condition in the Where part of the code.
The stored date that it's finding is stored as text in your example.
I would recommend processing the date as a datetime instead of a string type of   datatype.

I would include that in the code below, but I'm not sure what the format looks like for your string of text.

%date% is the same thing as saying "Contains date".
This takes the date string, and tries to see if it matches in every position of characters from left to right.
So if your date text is 20200130, it will check to see if it matches 2date0200130, then tries 20date200130, then tries 202date00130, etc.
It will significantly increase the time it takes to process.

I also see that the date is being searched accidently two times instead of one.

I would recommend doing:

```
WHERE LTRIM(RTRIM(Column5)) LIKE 'date'
```

As for the Inner Joins, I would not use them.
Use the Left join, and then in the Where, I would make sure it had no Null values for that joined data.
This makes the Left Join work the same as the Inner Join and runs more optimally when you are running the query.

For Instance, the first Join would look like this:

```
FROM [table1]
LEFT JOIN [table2] ON [table2].ID = [table1].CustomerPersonID
WHERE table2.id IS NOT NULL
```

I see an error in the code in the Where statement:

```
AND table6.id = 5
OR tables6.id = 2
```

This should be:

```
AND (tables6.id = 5 OR tables6.id = 2)
```

So here should be an optimized version of your code:

```
SELECT [table1].Column1 AS InvoiceNo,
'ND' AS VATRegistrationNumber,
'ND' AS RegistrationNumber,
Column2 AS Country,
[table2].Column3 + ' ' + [table2].Column4 AS Name,
CAST([table1].Column5 AS date) AS InvoiceDate,
'SF' AS InvoiceType,
'' AS SpecialTaxation,
'' AS VATPointDate,
ROUND([table1Line].Column6, 2) AS TaxableValue,
(CASE WHEN [table1Line].Column7 = 9 THEN 'PVM2'
      WHEN [table1Line].Column7 = 21 THEN 'PVM1'
      WHEN [table1Line].Column7 = 0 THEN 'PVM14'
      ELSE '' END ) AS TaxCode,
CAST([table1Line].Column7 AS int) AS TaxPercentage,
table1Line.Column8 - ROUND([table1Line].Column6, 2) AS Amount,
'' AS VATPointDate2,
[table1].Column1 AS InvoiceNo,
'' AS ReferenceNo,
'' AS ReferenceDate,
[table1].CustomerPersonID AS CustomerID
FROM [table1]
LEFT JOIN [table2] ON [table2].ID = [table1].CustomerPersonID
LEFT JOIN [table3] ON [table3].ID = [table2].Column9
LEFT JOIN [table1Line] ON [table1Line].table1ID = [table1].ID
LEFT JOIN [table4] ON [table4].ID = table1Line.TaxID
LEFT JOIN [table5] ON [table5].ID = [table1].CompanyID
LEFT JOIN [table6] ON table6.ID = [table1].SalesChannelID
WHERE table2.ID IS NOT null
AND table3.ID IS NOT null
AND table1Line.ID IS NOT null
AND table4.ID IS NOT null
AND table5.ID IS NOT null
AND table6.ID IS NOT null
AND LTRIM(RTRIM(Column5)) LIKE 'date'
AND (table6.id = 5 OR table6.id = 2)
ORDER BY Column5 DESC;
```

Comment: *I also see that the date is being searched accidently two times instead of one.*. SQL Server's query planner handles that kind of duplicated filter perfectly, and wastes no query time.